# How can I change parameter context from supeuser to user in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I added my parameter to postgresql.conf. I want to give to all users the option to change the setting of this parameter in their sessions, but the user failed to change it.

I saw in pg_settings that the value of context field for this parameter is 'superuser'. How can I change it to 'user'?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

When you define the parameter in your C extension using `DefineCustomStringVariable` or friends, use `PGC_USERSET` rather than `PGC_SUSET` for the `context` parameter.